# Google Analytics API OAuth 2.0 Authorisation without popup

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api

The intention here is to retrieve my google analytics data using the [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api) and display it in a web page.

I can authenticate with no problem if I use the "popup" method where essentially this code is called:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
```

However, I don't want to have to click "Allow access" whenever I want to view this page. Especially as I intend for this to be viewable by multiple people in a CMS.

Seeing as it's my Google Analytics account, and I have registered the web application, is there no way of authenticating via javascript on page load without having to display a popup to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using this code check if user authorized your app

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
```

if you set immidiate true then it will not show popup if false it will show popup to user

in handleAuthResult

```
 handleAuthResult = function (authResult) {
var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
     // do your processing here
    } else {
    authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
}
```

}

```
handleAuthClick = function (event) {
gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: scopes,
    immediate: false
}, handleAuthResult);
return false;
```

}

i think it will help you

Comment: Thank you, that's a big help.

Comment: Could you explain it ? Even when I set immediate to true, I got a popup..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use OAuth Authentication.  Check out [this article](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2).  Once you have authorized once there would be no need for follow up authorization.